# JSon File first read as an object then as a Json

Tags: javascript, json

So my problem is pretty simple.

I have a Json File which contain : `{ "message": [] }`

In this File I'll add continuously messages by parsing it, pushing an item and "stringifying" it back.

Like this :

```
jf.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, json){
    json = JSON.parse(json)
    json.message.push({user: message.username, date: message.hour, message: message.text})
    json = JSON.stringify(json)
    jf.writeFile(file, json, 'utf8');
}
```

However when it is the first message basicJsonF is consider as an [object Object].
And as soon as I have a message in it is consider as a JSon file.

How could I (without an if condition) specify basicJsonF as a Json File?

### Edit :

I've found out a solution I guess is clean if anyone need it :

```
typeof(json) === 'object' ? null : json = JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: Hmmm? `var basicJsonF = '{ "message": [] }'` is neither empty, nor JSON, not a file.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it has been validate by http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Baldráni — Error: Parse error on line 1:
var basicJsonF = '{ 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: No, [it does not](https://i.imgur.com/wibzYMX.png). People tend to confuse JavaScript with JSON (files used to be clear, though). Yes, I understand what you mean but when writing code these details matter because computers do not guess. We can't determine what's wrong with your code because the code you've shared is missing vital parts and does not really run.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, and what sense I can make out of it doesn't match my expectations of the code. You need to supply a proper [mcve]. Idealy in the form of a live demo using the snippets feature available in the Stackoverflow editor.

Comment: @Quentin well I've edited it so It's a bit more clear. However I think I've found a proper solution but still I'd like to understand why is it not consider as a json by `JSON.parse()` in the first time?

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve]. I could *probably* recreate all the bits of code you left out (fixing the syntax error, sticking dummy data in the many undefined variables, including the one which identifies which module you are using to read and write files), but I'm not being paid enough for that.

Comment: Your edit does not make so much sense. You check if it is an object, than you set the json to `null / undefined` and if it is no an object you parse it into an object

Comment: @Quentin the point is to make something that could be readable. 
You say it like I should provide node modules. Which I do not think make my point at all.
With the information provided (after my edit for making it cleaner) you could clearly answer a simple question (which it should be). 
Ps : I didn't knew you were getting paid for answering question on SO.

Comment: @DomeTune the null does not set anything it is just so It doesn't actually do an action.

Comment: @Baldráni – "You say it like I should provide node modules." — You should tell us which modules you are using (and remove ones that are not needed to reproduce the problem). Have you read [mcve]?

Comment: @Baldráni — "I didn't knew you were getting paid for answering question on SO" — I'm not. $0 is not enough money to spend trying to run your code with everything missing from it.

Answer (score 1):

This Code Snippet works fine for what you wanna do. You only need to write the `json` into your file.

```js
var message = { username: "TestUser", hour: new Date(), text: "HEY THERE!" };
var jsonBasicFile = '{ "message": [] }';
console.log(jsonBasicFile);
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonBasicFile);
console.log(obj);
obj.message.push({user: message.username, date: message.hour, message: message.text});
console.log(obj);
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Ho sry I have forgoten to precise but json = jsonFile ofc I've just cut a part of the whole function.